# Wordpress Nginx Security Best Practice

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-config

I'm thinking of switching from Apache to Nginx and I'm struggling to determine what's needed for WordPress specific security directives. Almost everything WordPress specific I've found so far breaks wp-admin, breaks content layouts, gives ajax errors or more.

The two most common suggestions seem to be:  [ethanpil/wp-secure.conf](https://gist.github.com/ethanpil/1bfd01a817a8198369efec5c4cde6628) and [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/nginx?domains.0.server.domain=www.example.com&domains.0.server.path=%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fhtml%2F&domains.0.server.wwwSubdomain=true&domains.0.php.wordPressRules=true&global.php.phpServer=%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fphp%2Fphp7.4-fpm.sock&global.nginx.user=nginx).

Any suggestions or better sources?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put essential pieces of secure WordPress NGINX configuration together, [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/best-practice-secure-nginx-configuration-for-wordpress).

The most secure approach would be to *whitelist* the files which can be run through PHP interpreter, and dismiss requests for all others with an HTTP status 404.

```
    location / {

        # any URI without extension is routed through PHP-FPM (WordPress controller)
        location ~ ^[^.]*$ {
            length_hiding on;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
            include includes/php-example.com.conf;
        }

        # allow only a handful of PHP files in root directory to be interpreted
        # wp-cron.php ommited on purpose as it should *not* be web accessible, see proper setup
        # https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/wordpress/wordpress-cron-optimization
        location ~ ^/wp-(?:links-opml|login|mail|signup|trackback)\.php$ {
            length_hiding on;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include includes/php-example.com.conf;
        }

        # other PHP files "do not exist"
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
    }
```

Finally, it is crucial to disable any PHP execution under `/wp-content/`:

```
    location /wp-content/ { 
        # contents under wp-content are typically highly cacheable
        immutable on;
        # hide and do not interpret internal plugin or user uploaded scripts
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
    }
```

If you feel like you have to have some script launched as `/wp-content/some.php` URI, you likely have a bad plugin that needs to be removed, or (rarely) whitelist if for running through PHP-FPM.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it.